# How to create dynamic button inside a hero card in microsoft bot framework using python

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot

```
def suggestion_card(self) -> Attachment:
    appID = ['11111', '22222']
    appName1 = UserAccessManagement.getAppName(appID1)
    appName2 = UserAccessManagement.getAppName(appID2)
    card = HeroCard(
        text = You have access for following applications , 
        buttons=[CardAction(
            type=ActionTypes.im_back,title="a",value="1"),CardAction(
            type=ActionTypes.im_back,title="b",value="2")])
    return CardFactory.hero_card(card)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to provide an explanation of your question rather than just posting code. It looks like you already know how to put buttons in hero cards, so what's wrong with the code you have now? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?